# Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm trying to add the HtmlServiceProvider with Laravel 5.

I keep getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 6391:
>   Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

This is how my providers look like:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

],
```

This is how my aliases look ik app.php:

```
'aliases' => [

    'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
    'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
    'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
    'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
    'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',

],
```

At last i have added this inside my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
},
```

Somehow i keep getting this error so im hoping someone can help me out with this :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run `composer update` after adding it to your `composer.json`?

Comment: Thanks to your comment i double checked it and i was doing composer update all the time in the wrong project folder inside homestead! Got it working now :)

Comment: `illuminate/html` is deprecated https://laravel-news.com/2015/02/new-community-project-laravel-collective/

Comment: This is a big problem in terms of automating deployments, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: @surfer190 no it's not. Deployments should use `composer install` not `composer update` to install the exact versions specified in `composer.lock`. There are no pre-install-cmd scripts so `install` doesn't attempt to load the config files. Now in this specific case, where the package name/namespace was changed, that should be caught before deploying...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First add this line to ***composer.json***

```
"illuminate/html": "~5.0"
```

Then do a `composer update`
Wait for the update to finish, then open ***config/app.php*** add this:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

to the `providers` array and this:

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

to the `aliases` array, and be sure when you use Html in blade or wherever use it in lowercase 'Html' not HTML

Here is a reference link: http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/class-illuminatehtmlhtmlserviceprovider.html

Comment: Please note that, as this answer says, you first add the `composer.json` line, then do an update, then add the lines to `app.php`. You can't combine the two steps and have it work.

Comment: Please note the answer with laravelcollective/html package as the Illuminate one is now depreciated.

Answer (score 30):

Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider is not a core element anymore. Laravel components that have been removed from the core framework are available on laravelcollective.com your html & forms components can be found here:

http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

add this to your composer.json :

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

then update composer:

```
composer update
```

then add providers in config/app.php

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

and finally add two aliases in the same file:

```
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Answer (score 14):

Illuminate/HTML package has been deprecated

Use:laravelcollective/html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991188/3327198

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Add this lines in config/app.php

in providers group:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

in aliases group:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps
Edit your project's composer.json file.

```
"require": {
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

}

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

composer update

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    // ...
  ],

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
```

],

Comment: This is a good answer, I think you should rate the correct answer made above than trying to get your own answer which isn't more precise as Arlind did.

Answer (score 1):

Me I found another cause for this issue:

in ../Vendor directory sometimes there is a file called "config.php", either delete that file completely or find in there some thing like 
this line:

```
array (
  ...
  28 => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  ...
),
```

, and remove the line, and then do the "composer update" command, this will help. (It helped me too).

Comment: I can't believe I'm the first person to up-vote this answer. In my case I had already switched from the Illuminate to the LaravelCollective version, but still got the issue whilst deploying to my test environment. The solution was to rm boostrap/cache/*, which just removes config.php and services.json. For some reason, even though I had removed all references to the old version and successfully run composer update, artisan clear-compiled was still failing. Removing those two files in boostrap/cache two files solved the problem.

Comment: They were not interested in this answer as Illuminate\Html was removed from core Laravel. Thanks for up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like this
`Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`  and

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: What is the significance of that, being `::class` addition to the end? I've noticed that change in the last six months of Laravel.

Comment: This returns the class name. If you use this class name will be no more hard coded.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates it can't find the service provider so make sure you do a composer update.  If you did do a composer update check your vendor folder to make sure it pulled in the dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Double check when Updating your composer, whether you're in the right directory

Comment: It's really silly, but that was my problem :-P I couldn't imagine that such thing can happen to me :)

Answer (score -1):

Run this in cmd

```
php artisan  Illuminate\Html
```

and then add variables in app.php

Answer (score -2):

For use laravel html helper you need to require dependency in composer.json file and use namespance.For full process follow my blog.
http://www.kingpabel.com/laravel-html-helper/