# Laravel 5 Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\FormFacade' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Ok, this is driving me mad. I'm trying to include forms functionalities with FormFacade with Laravel 5, but I keep getting this error:

```
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\FormFacade' not found
```

I'll write down what I have done:

- After laravel 5 installation, I added [FormFacade](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php) to laravel.
- Updated the app.php file with the following lines:

  ```
  Providers:
  'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',



   Aliases: 
  'Form' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HtmlFacade',
  ```
- Then, I checked my composer.json file:

  ```
  "require": {
      "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
      "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
  },
  ```
- Did a composer update
- Checked if I actually downloaded the files

All of this is done, but still I cannot find whats going wrong. I searched for help but nothing seems to work.

Search effort:

- Laracasts tutorial
- [Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5)
- http://tutsnare.com/class-form-or-html-not-found-in-laravel-5/

Still no luck. Have I missed something?

PS: I'm running on windows.

Comment: You also want to update your requirement to `laravelcollective/html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aliases are wrong. You should use the facades from `Illuminate\Html`:

```
'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
```

Comment: what is your Laravel version?