# laravel 5 .. ubuntu .. command line

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

I am working using laravel5 php framework on ubuntu and I have 2 problems

1- when I try to use the composer to require anything .. it doesnt work
2- when i tried to make some changes to illuminate/Html .. it doesn't work too
so after that when i tried to use the artisan to serve my project I got that error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /home/shaimaa/Sites/Laravel5/eoswdt/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 5617
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found' in /home/shaimaa/Sites/Laravel5/eoswdt/storage/framework/compiled.php:5617
Stack trace:
#0 /home/shaimaa/Sites/Laravel5/eoswdt/storage/framework/compiled.php(1500): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#2 {main}
```

Comment: Do this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following in your composer

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

Inside your config/app.php add the following codes inside it

In the 'providers' => [ ..]

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

And in the

'aliases' => [ ..]

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

And then refresh the page you should find that it should be working.