# Laravel 5 and Illuminate/html

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use `{{ HTML }}` in my project however I am running into several errors. I researched on internet about the problem, and I believe I am doing the right steps, however, I keep falling in the same error while I am trying to load my master page.

> FatalErrorException in ... line 9: Class 'HTML' not found

So what I did was:

- Edited the `composer.json` file and added `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` under `require {}`
- Run `composer update` (everything seems fine)
- Added: 
  `providers => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',` as well as

  ```
  `aliasses => 
  'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
  ```

---

*(Even though the ones already placed under aliasses and providers are as follows which seems the ones I added looks quite different than the rest:*

```
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', // The one I added

   'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', // I added
    'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade', // I added
```

---

And here is the snippet version of my `master.blade.php`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset = "UTF-8">

        <title></title>

        {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}      // Line 9
        {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}   // Line 10
        {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.js') }}   // Line 11

    </head>
```

The error I am getting is:

> FatalErrorException in ### line 9:
>   Class 'HTML' not found
>   in
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laratest/storage/framework/views/### line 9

---

I was benefiting from several tutorials such as [This one on YouTube](https://youtu.be/9MGBdy_Sqjg) and [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10). I also found a [Solved-tagged question](http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5) which is addressing the same issue but did not fix the issue in my case.

*Edit: Also changing to `{!! HTML !!}` is not working either*

Comment: I don't think this is your exact issue, but you alias the facade as `Html` but address it as `HTML`. More importantly (and it still probably won't fix your issue) you should upgrade to the community-led continuation of the illuminate/html package: [laravelcollective/html](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html)

Comment: check your case-sensitivity consistency when referencing html/HTML in the code (happened to me, was the fix)

Comment: when I try `{{ Html:.... }}`, I ended up receiving errors: 1) _ErrorException in Manager.php line 137:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'username' (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laratest/resources/views/master.blade.php)_ 2) _ErrorException in Manager.php line 137:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'username'_

Comment: As I say, try changing your package to the community-driven one (laravel collective) - the illuminate/html only goes as far as 5.0, so if you're using 5.1 you should upgrade anyway.

Comment: @alexrussell, so what you are suggesting me is removing these 3 rows that I have added in config>app.php (illuminate/html) as well as removing illuminate/html from composer.json; and then composer install laravelcollective/html ?

Comment: Remove `illuminate/html`, since it is deprecated. Do `composer require laravelcollective/html`. Remove your `vendor` folder,  do `composer install`. This worked for me when I had the same issue you are having. Also make sure you test it in a route closure, since `Html` or `HTML` can live in layouts and subviews.

Comment: HTML alias in app.php is case sensitive

Comment: @senty yes exactly - user2094178 expands on my advice with somewhat more precise instructions. See docs [here](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) for how to set up the laravelcollective HTML and Form facades.

Answer (score 3):

**Illuminate/HTML package has been deprecated**

**Use:laravelcollective/html**

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Add this lines in config/app.php

in providers group:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

in aliases group:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

First the facades aren't correct.

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', // FormFacade not HtmlFacade
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

The facade is `Html` not `HTML`.

```
<!-- This won't work -->
{!! HTML::script('js/jquery.js') !!}

<!-- This should work -->
{!! Html::script('js/jquery.js') !!}
```

Or you could change the facade key to `HTML` and then you can use `HTML::script(...)`.

```
'HTML'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

Comment: I corrected everything as you showed. However, this time, I ran into bunch of errors under 2 headings.. **1)** _ErrorException in Manager.php line 137:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'username'_ **2)** _ErrorException in Manager.php line 137:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'username' (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laratest/resources/views/master.blade.php)_

Comment: In the blade template do you have something like this: `Auth::username()`?

Answer (score 0):

In migrating to 5.1 I found the same issue - it appears as though the HTML class no longer supports the script and style methods.

Instead, use:

```
{{ URL::asset('yourassetpath') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{!! HTML !!}
```

and, don't forgot to `composer dumpautoload`.

See, if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried that `{!! HTML !!} ` . Just edited the OP. Sorry for writing `{!! HTML !}}`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using two different aliases to the same facade. the correct facades are

```
'Form' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade\HtmlFacade::class,
```

this should work

p.s. as of laravel 5.1 you should use facadeName::class

Comment: He tried this: {!! HTML !}}  which is wrong. Look closely.

Comment: @GauravDave, @elibyy. I tried {!! HTML !!}. I'm sorry for the misclick on OP. I just edited it.. Also I now tried:  `'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`
`'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class, ` as you said, but still the same error.

Comment: notice I've written Html and not HTML try to change between them because AFAIK it's case sensitive