# FatalErrorException in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 36: laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am getting following error 
FatalErrorException in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 36:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

my app.php file is

```
<?php

return [


    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),


    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),


    'url' => 'http://localhost',


    'timezone' => 'UTC',


    'locale' => 'en',


    'fallback_locale' => 'en',


    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',


    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),


    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],


    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
        'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',

    ],

];
```

And signup_form.blade.php file is

```
<h1>signupform</h1>

<div  class="signup-form">
  {!! Form::open() !!}

  {!! Form::text('email','',array('class'=>'email','id'=>"email","placeholder"=>'Email address'))!!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
```

And my routes.php file

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('home', function () {
    echo 'welome home';
});

Route::get('signup', 'Auth\HomeController@signupform');
```

whenever i open the form in browser it shows the above error.

Comment: Try to replace `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`, with `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class`, in `app.php`

Comment: @Moppo i changed it but still it is giving same error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to remove:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

and

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

form your `config/app.php

then remove from your `composer.json` `illuminate/html` then add to your `composer.json`:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.*"
```

in `require` section

then run `composer install`

And further you need to follow instructions for https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation to complete this package installation

**EDIT** IT might be not working at this moment because of this: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/133 - it will be probably solved after merging this PR: https://github.com/illuminate/html/pull/31/files

Comment: Thanks!, its was very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 12):

First, in the `composer.json` file  need to replace:

```
"illuminate/html": "^5.0"
```

with

```
"laravelcollective/html":"5.2.*"
```

Next you need update the composer from the terminal by typing this command in your terminal: `composer update`.

Next, in the `config/app.php` file, you replace the:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class'`
```

with

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class'
```

Next you replace these two classes aliases:

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

with

```
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Lastly, you need to update your routes.php file by replacing the 'web' middleware with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () use ($router) {
    $router->resource('blogs', 'BlogsController');
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. There was a typos (':class' instead of '::class) corrected!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial on [LaravelCollective.com](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#installation).

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" that worked for me is the one mentioned above because Illuminate/HTML package has been deprecated:

Use:laravelcollective/html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991188/3327198

In the terminal (CLI): *composer require laravelcollective/html*

Add this lines in config/app.php
IN PROVIDERS GROUP:

*Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,*

IN ALIASES GROUP:
*'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,*

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me
Change the name of all "bindShared" functions into "singleton" in the vendor\illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider.php file

For example:
Change

```
$this->app->bindShared('html', function($app)
{
   return new HtmlBuilder($app['url']);
});
```

into

```
$this->app->singleton('html', function($app)
{
   return new HtmlBuilder($app['url']);
});
```