# Laravel Upgrading To 5.2.0 From 5.1 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Getting the error on `composer update` command.

[image]

My composer.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-paginateroute": "^2.0",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "~2.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~5.0",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to remove this outdated package (taken out of the core and no longer supported):

```
"illuminate/html": "^5.0",
```

When you remove it, you need to also remove its service providers / aliases. So, if you open up `config/app.php`, you will see a providers and aliases section. Remove these lines of code if you haven't done so already.

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'

'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

In place of it, you should install the Laravel collective package. To install that, replace the `illuminate/html` package with this:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

Then in your `config/app.php` file, add this to your providers array:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class
```

and this to your aliases array:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

The docs can be found here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: If you are still getting errors, just put a caret before the version number:
`"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.6"`

Comment: where do i put "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.6" ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationbindshared

Quote "bindShared has been renamed to $app->singleton()"

**[Edit]**
I think you have something is your own custom code what need to be changed from : $this->app->bindShared() to: $this->app->singleton().

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by the steps mentioned in [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414389/fatalerrorexception-in-htmlserviceprovider-php-line-36-laravel) [Link2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

After the upgrade please make sure all the **Deprecations** mentioned in Link2 are corrected in your current app. For me `Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware` had to be removed from all the Middlewares.

Also I had to install latest version of certain packages like `"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.1.1",`