# Error after adding HTML and Forms in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Inside config/app.php file, I added the service provider to the list:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

And added the aliases:

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

But I get:

> FatalErrorException in HtmlServiceProvider.php line 36: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**
Go to the file `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` and replace `bindShare` with `singleton`. This will solve your problem.

`bindShared` has been renamed to `$app->singleton()`.

This would change the core files and is nit recommended. But if are just looking for a quick fix, this would help. But I strongly suggest you to follow the second solution.

**Solution 2**

The main problem is because you are using the package `Illuminate/HTML` which is no longer mainted. You can use `Laravelcollective/HTML` instead of this.

First, comment out the references to `Illuminate\Html` in your `config/app.php.`

Next, do composer remove `illuminate/html`.

After that, do `composer require laravelcollective/html`.

Now uncomment the `Illuminate\Html` items in your `config/app.php` file and update references to `Collective\Html` instead of `Illuminate\Html`.

Comment: "Solution 1" should be removed. First, modifying core files is rarely a good solution. Second, the way it is worded, it sounds like you're saying to rename a method in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`, which would cause many issues. "Solution 2" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow below steps to add HTML and FORM classes in laravel 5.

first open composer.JSON file and write following line after "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
            put comma(,) at last

```
         "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"

        now open command promt and type command "composer update"
        It will take some time to upgrade.

        after complete upgradation Register the service provider in config/app.php by adding the following value into the providers array:

            Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

        Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

         'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
         'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

See this post
[htmlserviceprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414389/fatalerrorexception-in-htmlserviceprovider-php-line-36-laravel)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Also, you should raise a "duplicate" flag, if you have not.

Comment: I know but i am ban . and can not flag.