# Laravel : "Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found" error on terminal

Tags: laravel-5.1

I read that `"illuminate/html": "5.*",` is no longer maintained, so I thought I should move into this : http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

I get an error when I try to update composer via `composer update`, it says

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] 
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I couldn't understand what's causing this.

Here's my composer.json's require part

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1"
  },
```

app.php Providers section

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

app.php alisases section

```
'aliases' => [
'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

],
```

Comment: Here is a post on how to fix the error http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/class-illuminatehtmlhtmlserviceprovider.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem, but I'm not sure it's the right solution.

I changed these in composer.json from

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan optimize"
],
```

to this

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize"
],
```

Source : https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/54#issuecomment-127351058

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5); you need to first add

```
"illuminate/html": "~5.0"
```

to composer.json do a

```
composer update
```

and then modify the app.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also run

```
Composer install
```