# ServiceProvider not found Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to create a custom package for Laravel 5.0 based on this [tutorials](http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/creating-custom-laravel-5-packages/)

The folder structure and service providers are exactly same, but some how the Serviceprovider is not updating autoload_namespace.php.

I already added my service provider in app/config.php

```
'Walkswithme\Users\UsersServiceProvider',
```

In my root composer.json I have following code.

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Walkswithme\\Users\\": "packages/walkswithme/users/src"
    }
```

Under my packages folder files struture is as follows.

```
 walkswithme
    users
      src
         models
         controllers
         views
         UsersServiceProvider.php
         routes.php 
      composer.json
```

I can't use Laravel 5.1 it requires php 5.5.9 , Other wise I can user artisan packager command.

The error is getting is as follows.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   
  Class 'Walkswithme\Users\UsersServiceProvider' not found
```

Any help will be appreciated last 3hrs I'm digging on it.

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Yes, I solved it, `composer dumpautoload` doesn't help but `composer dumpautoload -o` works for me

Comment: There is a good resource here, an answer made by Arlind, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself ,

I tried `composer dumpautoload -o` so it works for me.

Also some time needs `composer clearcache` too.

Hope it helps someone else..

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
Class 'Jubeki\LaravelCodeStyle\ServiceProvider' not found
```

And I just run

```
composer require jubeki/laravel-code-style --dev
```

In another folder (not where my common composer.json is located)

Maybe it also can help someone :)

Just check the place of the new bundle installation folder.