# Laravel 5 Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I know there are a bunch of other questions floating around out there with the same error, such as: [Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5)

My problem is that I've followed all suggested steps to solve this on my local (XAMPP), and it fixed it without a hitch. The issue is when I went to deploy to my AWS ubuntu box (nginx). I followed all the usual instructions: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation

My providers and aliases had been added when I did a git pull from what I had pushed from my local. Perhaps this file should have been gitignored, and the change made manually on the server?

```
Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

I then manually added:

```
Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's composer.json file to require laravelcollective/html.

"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

And finally, I ran:

```
composer.phar update
```

It was running this command that throws the error:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/cbt/vendor/compiled.php on line 6



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/cbt/vendor/compiled.php on line



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-auties] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ...
```

I then tried running php artisan clear-compiled, to see if that would do anything, and got:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/cbt/vendor/compiled.php on line 6716



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I know my nginx ubuntu environment is not the same as a windows xampp env, but I'm still unsure why following the Laravel-provided instructions for adding this don't seem to working. Would greatly appreciate some advice on this.

Cheers!

Comment: did you try `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: This did not seem to help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you update your composer it will check the providers. Because you haven't installed `laravelcollective/html` yet he can't find it and throws an error:

So first require your packeges, then add them to the config file.

You can also work with `composer require laravelcollective/html`, it will add it to the json file automatically. Then it doesn't matter if you have added them before or not because the config file won't be checked.

Comment: Exactly what I had to do, thank you so much! I should have known order of operations always matter.

Comment: I would add to this that after running `composer require larevelcollective/html' you also need to add ':5.2' or whatever version you are using. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and this answer gave me the correct solution, but I had to add the version at the end.

Answer (score 14):

I have encountered the same error on Laravel 5.2.*, followed instruction here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html, but did not work.

The other way to fix it, on your CLI, run:

**$ composer dump-autoload**

Then run:

**$ composer update**

This works for me. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Laravel 5.2, try adding this to your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
    ... 
},
```

Comment: close but you need to require laravelcollective/html: 5.2, I tried this way and it didn't work until I required in the console

Answer (score 0):

Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original content.

> [ErrorException]
> copy(/home/zahid/.composer/cache/files/laravelcollective/html/20e9e29d83e23aba16dc4b8d93d0757e1541f076.zip):
> failed to open stream: Permiss     ion denied

Command: `composer require laravelcollective/html --prefer-source`

then it work

Answer (score 0):

First try **composer update** . It will update all dependencies but in case it doesn’t work delete vendor folder of your project and type **composer install**  and run in cli which again add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel 10.x

Package ***laravelcollective/html***
is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
Use

```
composer require spatie/laravel-html
```