# I downloaded a laravel project online and its not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I downloaded a laravel project online from [link](https://itsourcecode.com/free-projects/laravel/online-crime-reporting-system-project-in-laravel-with-source-code/)
I ran the command is ***composer update*** and ***composer install***.
The error i'm seeing is:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class "Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider" not found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

After deleting vendor file and running ***composer install*** and ***composer update*** im getting this

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZAlert\app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php on line 27
> In EventServiceProvider.php line 27:
>
> Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

I was expecting this to run in laravel 9

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32795685/9077347

Comment: `composer update` updates your dependencies to the latest version which is compatible with your env. I recommend to remove `vendor` directory then just run `composer install`.

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost i did what you've written but same error is being displayed again

Comment: @IbrahimHammed It did not solved my issus now its showing `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your service provider php file

> Class"Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider

"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this library missed in your composer.json or you didn't run composer install
Please follow the nexts steps:
1 - require the package in "composer.json" :

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0" check the right version for your project
```

2 - Run

```
composer install
```

3 - Add this to config/app.php providers array :

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

4- And this to the aliases array :

```
 'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
 'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

5- optional step

```
composer dump -o
```

that should resolve your issue , let me know if you need any help