# After updating composer the illuminate/HTML package got uninstalled ,

Tags: html, laravel-5, composer-php

I updated my composer while trying to install some packages , The composer actually uninstalled everything else and installed some of the packages,

Now when I am doing

```
php artisan serve
```

Its saying illuminate\html\htmlserviceprovider not found .

My composer looks like this

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "~5.0",
         "bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
    },
```

Before the Website was running fine .

Can any one help me out , I tried to reinstall the HTML packages but it says  nothing to be downloaded

Thanks

Comment: If you want to **install** packages, then you need to use `composer install`. Issuing the `update` command downloads the latest versions of your packages (of course based on what your `composer.json` file looks like)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5)

Comment: @Avalanche I run the command composer install but it says nothing to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this line and if not add it to the app.php file in config in Service providers

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and this one to the aliases

```
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Comment: are you sure you are updating the correct file? you may be in another directory in your ssh connection.