# How to Automate Adding Service Providers on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

So according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541051/class-illuminate-html-htmlserviceprovider-not-found-laravel-5) the only way to add service providers is to first run `composer update` and `composer install`.

This becomes a problem in terms of automation, as the service provider has already been added to `config/app.php` in the code repo.

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    /** Forum **/
    'Riari\Forum\ForumServiceProvider',
    'Riari\Forum\Frontend\ForumFrontendServiceProvider',

],
```

So running `composer update` and `composer install` fails with:

```
[RuntimeException] Error Output: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Riari\Forum\Frontend\ForumFrontendServiceProvider' not found in /repo/myshares/myshares/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 6892
```

As far as I can see the only way is to run `composer update` first and then *manually* add to `config/app.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run your `composer install` or `composer update` with the parameter `--no-scripts`.

```
composer install --no-scripts
composer update --no-scripts
```

Laravel will run a few commands before installing or updating, that use the `artisan` script which will throw this error at you because it initiates a Laravel instance.

After composer has run you can always manually run the artisan commands (in this case `php artisan clear-compiled`).